# silverstripe widgets: define "allowed widgets" for widget areas

Tags: widget, silverstripe

in the current project I need two widget areas. The widget areas should allow just certain widgets to be added. So there are widgets that should for example just be available in widget area ONE.
Is there a way to set "allowed widgets" for widget area? Similar to "allowed_children" for pages?
Thx,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Widget module on GitHub, looks this functionality was added not long ago:
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-widgets/pull/51

**Widget.php**

```
...
public static $only_available_in = array();
...
```

You should be able to define which areas your Widgets are available in by setting the `$only_available_in` array for each widget.